# Count where conditions are different

Tags: sql-server-2012

I've been trying to optimize one of my more bulky db views.

Presently, I'm just using sub-selects 5 times to get the count of the company ID's.

```
(Select count(id) from company table where prospecting.stage = 'qualify') as Qualify,
(Select count(id) from company table where prospecting.stage = 'targetted') as Targetted,
```

Each company goes through 5 stages, I simply want to count the amount of companies in each stage by company location in separate columns.

I'm trying to do this in one select, but I am getting a bit stuck.

```
 SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN prospecting.stage = 'Qualify' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)) as [Qualified]
 SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN prospecting.stage = 'Targetted' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)) as [Targetted]
```

So it ends up looking something along these lines:

```
     Location | Stage: Qualify | Stage: Targetted | Stage 3 | Stage 4 | Stage 5 | Total
```

Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery. -Makes sense.

So I need to count the Company.ID where the prospecting.stage = 'XYZ' into separate rows per stage.

Any advice? :(

Comment: In the future you might want to provide information on what tables you are accessing and how they are related - knowing that makes it a lot easier to provide proper answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `count` function and change the datatype from char to int in the case expressions. Your expressions should look like this:

```
  SUM(CASE WHEN prospecting.stage = 'Qualify' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Qualified]
```

Comment: Oh my god, it was that simple! O_O

Comment: Thanks for the help, I clearly understand where I was going wrong now! :) 

Much appreciated. :)